# Paypal Primary Receiver Pays the Fee in a Chained Payment

Tags: paypal, chained-payments

does anyone know exactly how the Paypal charges work for chained payments?

We're developing an app where receiver 1 will keep 95% of the sender's amount.
So ... sender sends $100, and the receiver 1 would keep $95.

The remaining $5 would be split between Paypal and the app (or receiver 2 essentially).

My question is whether Paypal charge a fee for sending the money to sender 1 (2.9% + $0.30 = $3.20) as well as a charge for sending the balance of the 5% to the app (receiver 2).

In other words ... after Paypal have taken their $3.20 chunk out of the original $5.00 that the receiver gives up ... will the remaining $1.80 go to the app (receiver 2) ... or will Paypal take another chunk out of this ??

Thanks.

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Adaptive Payments is no longer supported and the alternative to it is Marketplaces.Please refer to the link below for more information on PayPal's Marketplaces and if its best suited for your business.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/

If you would like to be considered for PayPal for Marketplaces, you may submit your inquiry at the following link and they will be able to assist you with any questions:
https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/partner-program/contact-us

Thanks